# How should I interpret the gstreamer multifilesink timestamp property?

Tags: c, timestamp, gstreamer, glib

I am using a multifilesink element in C. multifilesink creates file names with an index, but I need file names with a timestamp. Conveniently, multifilesink sends a bus message after every file is written, and in the message data, it supplies a glib structure containing the file name and a timestamp. I have set up code to watch for the message and call a function to rename each file like this:

"file-01.jpg" becomes "file-DDMMYYYY_HHMMSS.sss.jpg"

I can successfully receive the message and call my function every time a file is written.

The problem is that I do not understand the value of the timestamp. It does not appear to be a unix epoch time, it is not monotonic, and often, the value is negative or zero.

```
// My function to handle multifilesink messages
static gboolean HandleElementMessages( GstMessage *MessagePtr )
{
    const GstStructure* MessageStructurePtr;
    gboolean success = TRUE;

    MessageStructurePtr = gst_message_get_structure( MessagePtr );
    g_print( "Received an element message from an element of type \"%s\" at time %ld\n", 
        gst_structure_get_name( MessageStructurePtr ), 
        GST_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP( MessageStructurePtr ) 
        );

    return success;
} // End of HandleElementMessages()
```

I expect that GST_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP() should return a monotonically increasing value that is related to the epoch or some starting point that I can understand. Instead, I see results like this:

```
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time 3282
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time 0
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time 2
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time 0
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time 0
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time 140662536522192
Received an element message from an element of type "GstMultiFileSink" at time -3543839906708188932
...
```

Comment: GST_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP() expects a GstMessage* argument, you seem to provide a GstStructure* ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. When I fix this, it always returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code what structure is being send to the bus:

```
  s = gst_structure_new ("GstMultiFileSink",
      "filename", G_TYPE_STRING, filename,
      "index", G_TYPE_INT, multifilesink->index,
      "timestamp", G_TYPE_UINT64, timestamp,
      "stream-time", G_TYPE_UINT64, stream_time,
      "running-time", G_TYPE_UINT64, running_time,
      "duration", G_TYPE_UINT64, duration,
      "offset", G_TYPE_UINT64, offset,
      "offset-end", G_TYPE_UINT64, offset_end, NULL);
```

So when you get your structure you should use some of the `GstStructure` functions to obtain data you are interested in:

```
guint64 timestamp;

gst_structure_get_uint64(MessageStructurePtr, "timestamp", &timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does return a "reasonable" value. Disappointingly, it's the elapsed time since the beginning, not an absolute time.  I can certainly get absolute time in other ways, but it will always be inaccurate because it's being generated when the message is received, not when it's being sent. Despite this seeming like a tiny difference, for my application, it matters. I think this is the best I can expect unless I modify multifilesink itself.

Comment: My solution is to record a wall-clock Tzero upon the first file and then add the timestamp value to it when processing subsequent frames. This still suffers from recording the time of message processing, not origination, and also is susceptible to drift for long-duration processing, but it's a band-aid for now.

Comment: @Thagomizer We are running into a similar problem. Did you find your solution to be stable, or did you happen to find any improvements?

Comment: @Niru My solution was stable/adequate. Fortunately we didn't need to leave the executable running for more than a few days, and the drift wasn't significant. If I were to revisit this problem for a more thorough solution, I'd have to explore other ideas, probably somehow sending the time from the data originator along with the data, or some kind of periodic time sync with an external reference (as is commonly done in time-critical applications) along with characterizing the latency of transmission (like NTP).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to periodically (e.g. every 60s) udpate the (wall clock time <-> gstreamer pts timestamp) pair in multifilesink's sink pad probe. Then in your "HandleElementMessages" function, it will be convenient to calculate wall clock time when the file was processing, and can endure long time-duration.

Answer (score 1):

I can get a file containing the current time with the following code.

```
static long gst_multi_file_sink_get_timestamp(void)
{
  long millesec=0;
  struct timespec tms;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&tms);

  // get micro second
  /*
  long micros=0;
  micros = tms.tv_sec * 1000000;
  micros += tms.tv_nsec/1000;
  if (tms.tv_nsec % 1000 >= 500) {
    ++micros;
  }
  millesec = (long)(micros/1000);
  GST_DEBUG("Millesecond: %lu\n",millesec);
  */

  // get mille second
  millesec = tms.tv_sec * 1000;
  millesec += tms.tv_nsec/1000000;
  if (tms.tv_nsec % 1000000 >= 500) {
    ++millesec;
  }

  return millesec;
}
```

And call the function from where you create the file name.

```
  // filename = g_strdup_printf (multifilesink->filename,
  //     multifilesink->index);
  filename = g_strdup_printf (multifilesink->filename,
    gst_multi_file_sink_get_timestamp());
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. This is the same solution I used; see my comment "My solution is to..." in response to Florian's answer.